# Pattern matching product with arbitrary number of terms

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to write a function to convert an expression of the form

$$\alpha x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} ... x_N^{n_N}$$

(with some coefficient $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$) into a list of indices and powers

$$\{\{1,n_1\},\{2,n_2\},...,\{N,n_N\}\}.$$

for expressions of varying length (number of products $x_i^{n_i}$).

My natural choice for this was the `Cases` function with pattern matching. Something along the lines of, for a three-term product,

```
pattern = α_ x{i_}^ni_. x{j_}^nj_. x{k_}^nk_.
Cases[expr, pattern -> {{i,ni},{j,nj},{k,nk}}],
```

where I write `x{i_}` to denote `Subscript[x,i_]`.

My question is how to match a product of arbitrary length. Is there a way to write a pattern to match

$$\alpha \prod_j x_{i_j}^{n_{i_j}}$$

for an arbitrary $j$ and $i_j\in\mathbb{Z}$ *not* predefined.

Alternatively, if we assume the maximum $j$ is known, is there a way I can write a single pattern (along the lines of `pattern` above) such that each term is optional? I.e. modify `pattern` to also match 2-term and 1-term products.

Comment: I should comment that although this question is primarily about pattern matching, I am not tied to this approach if it is the 'wrong' way to attack problems like this in Mathematica

Comment: Can you provide the Mathematica code corresponding to the expression you have? Is it written as a `Product`, as a `Times`, as a `Dot`, or what? Your first equation is `Times`, your `pattern` has `Dot`s, but you ask about a `Product`

Comment: `list =Array[x, 5];
mono = a * x[1]^q1  x[2]^q2 x[3]^q3 x[4]^1 x[5]^0 ;
Cases[mono *Apply[Times,list]^m // PowerExpand,  x_^n_   :> {x, n}] /. m -> 0`

Comment: @bRost03, yes, I accept the way I had written the pattern was confusing - especially as in a rush I had used latex-style x_i to denote a subscript. The dots in the pattern should read `x^in_.` - *not* for a `Dot` but for an optional part of the pattern to include `x^1` terms. I've corrected the pattern now.

Comment: I use product in the mathematical sense as interchangeable with times, not because the expression used a `Product` function. I believe they will use `Times`.

Comment: I guess I'm also asking for specifics on the format. The highly upvoted answer will break if you give it something like `2 x^2 y^3 z`. What are the constraints on the form of your expressions?

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point on the answer breaking for that expression? Using their first suggestion returns `{{x, 2}, {y, 3}, z}`, or includes the 2 term also if you remove the `Rest`, which seems workable?

Comment: An example format of the input for illustration would be `Times[8, Power[Subscript[x, 1], 2], Power[Subscript[x, 2], 2]]`, a product of x powers and a coefficient. The coefficient in general would not be purely Numeric so will be split into the list in the same way as the x powers, but I can reconstruct it afterwards by filtering the output.

Comment: @CaileanWilkinson You consider `{{x, 2}, {y, 3}, z}` a valid solution? You don't want `{{x, 2}, {y, 3}, {z,1}}`?

Comment: @CaileanWilkinson It also should give you `{{Identity, 2}, {y, 3}, z}`, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127813/discussion-between-cailean-wilkinson-and-brost03).

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** ***"to apply the Times/Power -> List replacement only to powers of $x_i$"***

```
expr2 = -2 a^2 expr
```

[image]

```
expr2 /. m -> 5 /. Times[a___, p : (Power[_x, _] ..)] :> 
  {Times @ a, Sequence @@ ({p} /. Power -> List /. x -> Identity)}
```

> ```
> {-2 a^2 α, {1, n[1]}, {2, n[2]}, {3, n[3]}, {4, n[4]}, {5, n[5]}}
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
expr = α Product[Power[x[i], n[i]], {i, 1, m}]
```

[image]

With numeric `m` you can simply replace `Times` and `Power` with `List`:

```
Rest[expr /. m -> 5 /. Times | Power -> List] /. x -> Identity
```

> ```
>  {{1, n[1]}, {2, n[2]}, {3, n[3]}, {4, n[4]}, {5, n[5]}}
> ```

Also

```
Block[{Power = List, Times = List}, 
   Transpose @ First @ Rest[expr /. m -> 5]] /. x -> Identity
```

> ```
>  {{1, n[1]}, {2, n[2]}, {3, n[3]}, {4, n[4]}, {5, n[5]}}
> ```

and

```
First @ Cases[expr /. m -> 5, 
   Times[α, pat : __Power] :> ReplaceAll[x -> Identity] @* List @@@ {pat}, All]
```

> ```
> {{1, n[1]}, {2, n[2]}, {3, n[3]}, {4, n[4]}, {5, n[5]}}
> ```

Comment: @CaileanWilkinson, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I removed the comment asking for that when I realised I could just 'correct' for it by piecing the coefficient back together afterwards. Didn't realise you'd already seen it / started on an answer. Seems like a nicer approach to just not break up the coefficient in the first place as per your update. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If we can assume the variables are always in the form $x[i]$ then we have

```
f = With[{v = #}, {First[#], Exponent[v, #]} & /@ Cases[v, x[_], ∞]] &;
```

**EDIT:** for variables in the form $x_i$ just use `f = With[{v = #}, {# /. Subscript[x, a__] -> a, Exponent[v, #]} & /@ Cases[v, Subscript[x,_],∞]] &;`

This handles the initial coefficient more robustly than the other answer. The idea is the `Cases` identifies the variables and the `Map` gives back the format you like. So something like

```
test=8a^2 x[1]^q1 x[2]^q2 x[3]^q3 x[4]
f@test
```

gives

```
{{1,q1},{2,q2},{3,q3},{4,1}}
```

Note that the coefficient is filtered automatically and it works for an exponent of 1.

If we cannot assume the variables are always in the form $x_i$ and, like in a now deleted comment, the coefficient may be something like $8a^2$, then it's obviously impossible since we can't know if $a$ belongs to the coefficient or the variables. That aside, we can do something like

```
f[exp_, cof_] := Block[{exp2, vars, ind},
  exp2 = (exp/cof) /. Times -> List;
  vars = exp2 /. Times -> List /. Power[a_, b_] -> a;
  MapIndexed[(ind = First[#2]; {ind, Exponent[#1, vars[[ind]]]}) &, exp2]]
```

which takes in the coefficient as an argument. Again

```
test=8a^2 x[1]^q1 x[2]^q2 x[3]^q3 x[4]
f@test
```

gives

```
{{1,q1},{2,q2},{3,q3},{4,1}}
```

as desired.

If you don't know the coefficient apriori, you can put in 1 or simply use

```
f[exp_] := Block[{Times=List, vars, ind},
  vars = exp /. Power[a_, b_] -> a;
  MapIndexed[(ind = First[#2]; {ind, Exponent[#1, vars[[ind]]]}) &, exp]]
```

then filter the coefficient later like you said you can do in the comments.